# Controls all stuck in top left corner when I debug my VS for Mac iOS app

Tags: c#, ios, macos, visual-studio-mac

I've been working through the introductory Hello, iOS project in VS for Mac, and I believe I've done everything according to the instructions.  The [layout of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRxP4.png) looks fine, however when I debug my application, all the controls are [stuck in the top left of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyLdz.png) in the iOS simulator.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Since I can't add more than 2 links to my question yet, here's a link to the tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Xamarin code. Perhaps its not optimized for iOS 10.2 or Xcode 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I must have done something wrong the first time.  I deleted and recreated the app, and it worked fine the second time.